# MySQL Insert Into Error Code 1136

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-into

I am in MySQL Workbench 
I am have created a Table and now want to insert data, but MySQL says, "Error code:  1136 Column Count doesnt match value count at row 1) and this is slightly confusing.

Please can someone advise.

```
CREATE table 05FinancialForecast
(
ID INT,
Username VARCHAR (12),
Region VARCHAR (12),
ProductGroup VARCHAR (25),
Product VARCHAR (25),
Customer VARCHAR (30),
SalesRep VARCHAR (20),
ProductLine VARCHAR (15),
TransactionDate DATE, 
TransactionCode TEXT,
Units SMALLINT,
CountryCode VARCHAR(4),
GlobalUnit SMALLINT,
SALES SMALLINT,
2017Forecast SMALLINT,
2018Forecast SMALLINT,
2019Forecast SMALLINT,
2020Forecast SMALLINT,
2021Forecast SMALLINT,
2022Forecast SMALLINT,
2023Forecast SMALLINT,
2024Forecast SMALLINT,
2025Forecast SMALLINT,
2026Forecast SMALLINT,
2027Forecast SMALLINT,
2028Forecast SMALLINT
)



INSERT INTO 05financialforecast
(
ID, Username, Region, ProductGroup, Product, Customer, SalesRep, ProductLine, TransactionDate, TransactionCode,
Units, CountryCode, GlobalUnit, SALES, 2017Forecast ,2018Forecast, 2019Forecast, 2020Forecast, 2021Forecast,
2022Forecast, 2023Forecast, 2024Forecast, 2025Forecast, 2026Forecast, 2027Forecast, 2028Forecast 
) Values


(1,
"Shrik1",
"West",
"Freestyle",
"Carlota",
"BFGM company",
"Phlem",
"Beginner",
"01-05-2015",
"421251FreestyleWestPhlem",
20,
"AFG",
500,10000,250,23000,23500,24000,24500,25000,25500,26000,26500,27000,27500,28000,28500);
```

Comment: Sounds like a fairly self-explanatory error, have you done any research about it and/or have you counted how many fields you are attempting to insert, versus how many fields the table has?

Answer (score 0):

You're typing 27 values for 26 columns.